# Why the default value variable change as the changed variable value, Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

as you see the code, on the handleUpdateFilter function the second "if" some how defaultCourseData is filtered as filteredData of the first "if". Thank you for helping me!

```
    setup() {
    const course = ref();
    const defaultCourseData = null

    const gettingCourse = async () => {
      const { data } = await getCourse();
      
      defaultCourseData = data
      course.value = data;
    };

    const handleUpdateFilter = (data) => {
      // data is filtering value
      if (data.value.view) {
        const filteredData = defaultCourseData.sort((a, b) => b.luotXem - a.luotXem);
        course.value = filteredData;
      }
      if (!data.value.view) {
        course.value = defaultCourseData // This case some how defaultCourseData filtered too
      }
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      gettingCourse();
    });
    return {
      course,
      handleUpdateFilter,
      defaultCourseData
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your defaultCourseData variable isn't reactive.
Therefore it should be evaluated as null at every call.

Try this

```
defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const course = ref([]);
    const defaultCourseData = ref([]);

    const gettingCourse = async () => {
      const { data } = await getCourse();
      defaultCourseData.value = data
      course.value = data;
    };

    const handleUpdateFilter = (data) => {
      // data is filtering value
      if (data.value.view) {
        course.value = defaultCourseData.value.sort((a, b) => b.luotXem - a.luotXem);
      }
      if (!data.value.view) {
        course.value = defaultCourseData.value // This case some how defaultCourseData filtered too
      }
    };

    onMounted(async () => {
      await gettingCourse();
    });
    return {
      course,
      handleUpdateFilter,
      defaultCourseData
    };
})
```

Edit: The actual issue here was, that the defaultCourseData always returned a sorted array as Array.prototype.sort() mutates the Array.
So making a copy solves the issue.

```
if (data.value.view) {         course.value = [...defaultCourseData.value].sort((a, b) => b.luotXem - a.luotXem);       }
```

Comment: Still not working man, `defaultCourseData.value` still changed to filtered array

Comment: Is data actually giving you back an Object of "data.value" i.e., a Vue Ref<any> Type or is it just a "normal" Object i.e., { view: 'something' }?
Maybe your if clause never works correctly because you check for a field on data that doesn't exist?

Comment: No man, I also `console.log` the `defaultCourseData.value` in the second `if`, this array is sorted same as the first `if` data. The second `if` I'm checking if `data.value.view` is false, sendcond `if` is run but the problem is `defaultCourseData.value` always return sorted array value when `data.value.view` is false.

Comment: No algorithm using for `defaultCourseData.value` but some how it's alway changing to the sorted array.

Comment: Ah sorry then i misunderstood your question

You are always getting a sorted array because Array.prototype.sort() will mutate the original Array.
You have to create a copy of that i.e., `const sorted = [...arr].sort();`

In your case 
`if (data.value.view) {
        course.value = [...defaultCourseData.value].sort((a, b) => b.luotXem - a.luotXem);
      }`

Comment: Wooooooooooo, thanks man! I didn't know this, it's working, do you have facebook or something let us connect, I'll buy you a coffee

Comment: I don't really use facebook but you can connect with me on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/burak-cakmakoglu-24a15120a/ :)
If you'd accept my edited answer that'd be cool to 